# jQuery Prepend script from within document ready from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to follow Google's instructions to insert part of their Tag Manager code immediately after the opening body tag on a webpage.

However, I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` error, and it seems the `</noscript>` tag is closing the opening `<script>` tag.

My code is here:

```
echo <<<EOF
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('body').prepend('<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>');
});
</script>

EOF;
```

Obviously nesting the script/noscript tags is a bad idea, but I'm having trouble thinking of a workaround. I'm in WordPress, and there is no theme hook I can rely on the add the script to.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The Uncaught SyntaxError.. should contain the line in the domdocument where the error occurs. That line number is clickable, and will take you to inspect the line where it happens

Comment: New line before `height="0"`

Comment: I've removed the new line, and the error is gone, but the script is not appended. Any idea why please?

Comment: @robin please check whether the <noscript> tag is prepended to the body. It's not an actual script, rather it loads the iframe in case javascript is disabled - maybe it's already there in the DOM? Deleting the line-break works on my wordpress installation.

Comment: @Chri.s The noscript tag is there in the inspector but not the page source. In the inspector it has double quotes around it. Google Tag assistant (chrome extension) gives: `HTTP response code indicates tag failed to fire: Status 404. This could be due to an empty or un-published container`

Comment: ... which is another issue, now sorted. Those double quotes bother me, but google seems not to mind.

Comment: On a completely other note - you probably shouldn't try to add a `<noscript>` with a (java)script? ;) If javascript is deactivated, the iframe will not be prepended anyways. You have to add it directly in the file - unless I've misunderstood the purpose, that is.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. Wood for the trees and all that. Google accepts my code but I see the now obvious problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a "\" (backslash) at the end of the noscript tag to become like this "<\ /noscript>" :

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('body').prepend('<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
    <\/noscript>');
});
</script>
```